# Html5 number input step and precision

Tags: javascript, html, input, webforms

I can't find out how to define a step value and a precision to a input[number]

`1.01` is considered as invalid until I specify a step of `0.01`.
But In that case I can't specify a specific step.

Same issue with big number. If I specify a step of `1000` and the user type `1001` the value is considered **invalid**...

You can have a look to this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/u6Ma7/)

Comment: doesn't that make sense? I'm not familiar with the spec, but it seems obvious that only numbers that are a multiple of the step would be valid. What behavior are you hoping for?

Comment: First I want to use the HTML5 validation.
- I also want to allow increasing the value of the number input with huge number. But also set custom ones(not multiple of the [step]).
The HTML5 validation set my input as :invalid once I set a number not a multiple of the [step].

Comment: I have this same problem when using `step=.01` but a perfectly valid number for me is `1.00001` so it displays as `:invalid`. Did you ever find a work around?

Comment: No I didn't. I had to write my own validation logic.

Answer (score 32):

I guess you want to disable step validation. If so, `step="any"` should work.

Comment: You can add your own stepper UI.

Comment: sad limitation of html5 :(

Comment: I don't know if it changed since your comment but now adding `step="any"` doesn't desactivate the stepper functionnality. @YacineZalouani

Comment: @Veve: ow but it does, somewhat... By using the `step="any"`, the stepper functionality will fall back to default; that is `step="1"`. You can't change that. Actually YacineZaloani wanted to use `step="0.01"` but still validate a value of `1000` as "ok".

Comment: I owe you beer.

Answer (score 11):

You probably just need to define a correct step and an **initial value** that suits your purpose.

The role of the `value` attribute is not fully explained in the `step` attribute documentation http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp.

In the first input in your example, attributes are set to `value = 1.01` and `step = 1` (default value). The input will accept the following values: `1.01 + 1n`. where `n` is an integer value. Example of accepted values are: 1.01, 2.01, 3.01 and so on, as well as -0.99, -1.99 -1.99 and so on.

As a general rule, the accepted values will be:

[image: value + step * n]

Where
[image: n \in \mathbb{Z}].

You can have an idea of the accepted values by using the UP/DOWN arrow keys when the input is focused.

As suggested in previous answers, `step="any"` will disable the step validation, it won't disable the stepper functionality (`step` will defaults to 1), but will require to implement the step validation by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Definition and Usage](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp) of the `step` attribute:

> The step attribute specifies the legal number intervals for an 
>   element.

Once it is out of the intervals, the number is illegal.

Try using Javascript code to take care of your need.

Comment: Javascript code won't help me. Once I set a value not multiple of the [step] the input is flagged as :invalid

Comment: you'll have to write your own custom validation code then using javascript. You can't make HTML work in a way that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think a way to solve this problem is to use the [`stepUp` and `stepDown` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365348/html5-number-input-step-and-precision). To use it, you would set the `step` attribute to your precision, and with JavaScript use one of those two methods, which accept a unit to be multiplied by your precision when stepping. If your precision is `step="0.001"` you can use `inputEl.stepUp(1000)` to increment `1.000`.

I know this answer is late but hopefully it is helpful to others.