# Disable validation for step on number field

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code

```
<input name="contact" min="0" step="0.5" id="contact" size="4" maxlength="6" required="true" type="number"
```

Is there a way to disable the validation field does now? It will not let the numbers in the field if they are typed to be anything other than multiples of .5

Example of what I am talking about is here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2yudfxtv/)

If you end 5.6 in the field it becomes invalid.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html5 number input step and precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365348/html5-number-input-step-and-precision)

Comment: So then why have `step="0.5"`?

Comment: Are you saying you wish to only have decimal values?